# Travelling Salesman Brute Force Combinations

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I started writing some code today to test some different solutions to the traveling salesman problem. I have run some tests for the random algorithm and the nearest neighbor algorithm, however, I am struggling with the brute force method.

What my program does is ask the user how many cities they will add. It then asks them to input the cities name followed by their longitude and latitude. I have created a method to then generate a 2-dimensional array in which the distances between all cities are stored.

What I want my brute force algorithm to do is calculate the distance between all combinations of cities and at the end output the shortest distance.

For example:

3 cities are entered(New York, Paris, Shanghai)
The distances between them is then stored.

```
[0.0, 5834.0, 11851.0]
[5834.0, 0.0, 9257.0]
[11851.0, 9257.0, 0.0]
```

Now I want to work out all the possible combinations and their total distance:

```
NY-P-S-NY
NY-S-P-NY
P-NY-S-P
P-S-NY-P
S-NY-P-S
S-P-NY-S
```

My issue is avoiding the 0.0 distances from the array, which will obviously result in shorter routes.

Any help is much appreciated. Please note I am only just learning to code so if possible I prefer less efficient and easier to understand answers :)

The code below is my attempt of getting it to work for 4 cities, however, I wish for the program to be able to complete this task for any amount of cities. I am well aware what I tried is unsuccessful:

```
int numCities = weights.length();
      List<Integer> brute = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++){
        brute.add(i);
      }
      System.out.println(brute);
      double weight = 0.0;
      double tempWeight = 0.0;
      int temp1 = 0;
      int temp2 = 0;
      int temp3 = 0;
      int temp4 = 0;
      int removing = 0;
      int valuetoRemove = 0;
      for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++){
          temp2 = brute.get(b);
          //System.out.println(temp2);
          List<Integer> brute2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          brute2.addAll(brute);
          brute.remove(b);
          System.out.println(brute);
          for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++){
            temp3 = brute.get(c);
            //System.out.println(temp3);
            List<Integer> brute2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            brute2.addAll(brute);
            brute.remove(c);
            //System.out.println(brute);
            temp4 = brute.get(0);
            //System.out.println(temp4);
            //brute.remove(0);
            //System.out.println(brute);
            tempWeight = weights[temp1][temp2] + weights[temp2][temp3] + weights[temp3][temp4] +  weights[temp4][temp1]; 
            System.out.println(tempWeight);
            brute = brute2;
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you clarify this line? `My issue is avoiding the 0.0 distances from the array, which will obviously result in shorter routes.`

Comment: Yeah what I mean is I need to create loops which avoid trips inside of a city(NY-NY)

Comment: So the loop should only allow trips from for example NY to go to either S or P and not NY itself.

Comment: The way you create your data and your goal to do this for any number of cities conflict. You should try to use OOP to make your code more readable. Are you calculating the distance or are you hardcoding it?